# Calling a method when another method is called

Tags: c#, class, methods, partial-methods

This might be a stupid question, but here goes.

I have the following problem:

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public void SomethingAwesome()
    {
        //Awesome stuff happens here, but only when the Something() method
        //is called in the other classes.
    }
}

public class SomeClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public void Something()
    {
        //Something happens here
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass : MyBaseClass
{
    public void Something()
    {
        //Something else happens here
    }
}
```

**MyBaseClass** has a method which needs to be called when the **Something()** method is called in the class that inherits from it.

The idea behind this is that I need to log when this method is called for lots of boring corporate reasons. I would rather have a base class which automatically audits when a method is called, rather than having the developer call the method himself/herself.

Can something like this be achieved? If so, how?

I've considered partial methods, but that would require classes with the same name, which isn't possible in this scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern):

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    public void Something()
    {
        // Code from SomethingAwesome here, or keep SomethingAwesome
        // separate and call it from here
        SomethingImpl();
    }

    protected abstract void SomethingImpl();
}

public class SomeClass : MyBaseClass
{
    protected override SomethingImpl()
    {
        // Something happens here
    }
}
```

That's assuming you're happy for `MyBaseClass` to *have* a public `Something` method, of course - if it doesn't declare `Something` (in some way) then the two `Something` methods in the derived classes are unrelated.

Comment: This is somewhat what I am after, however the abstract SomethingImpl() needs to have an implementation. What I'm after is SomethingImpl() gets called in SomeClass, and called in the base class.

Comment: @helb: That *will* happen - because the only way of calling the subclass code is via the base class method.

Comment: @MikeEason: It doesn't need to have an implementation if it's abstract. I don't really follow your comment, but this really *is* what you want, I'm sure. If you don't want `MyBaseClass` to be abstract, you could make `SomethingImpl` just an empty virtual method instead.

Comment: I think there's a small typo: "SomethingAwful" should perhaps say "SomethingAwesome"?

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyBaseClass
{
    public void SomethingAwesome()
    {
         // ...
    }

    public void Something()
    {
         SomethingImpl();
         SomethingAwesome();
    }

    protected abstract void SomethingImpl();
}
```